# Python: Extract numeric values from a string, and add 1 to each value

Tags: python, python-3.x

A string contains sentences and numbers, which can be float or integer. I'm trying to add 1 to each of these numbers, then replace the previous numbers with new numbers in my string.

The code I have written adds 1 only to float numbers, whereas the integers remain the same.

```
s = """helllo everyone 12 32 how 6.326 is a going?
well 7.498 5.8 today Im going 3 to talk 8748 234.0 about
python 3 and compare it with python 2"""

newstr = ''.join((ch if ch in '0123456789.' else ' ') for ch in s)
print(newstr)

listOfNumbers = [float(i) for i in newstr.split()]
#print(f'list of number= {listOfNumbers}')

new_str = s
for digit in listOfNumbers:
    New_digit = digit+1
    print (New_digit)
    new_str = new_str.replace(str(digit),str(New_digit))
print(f'new_str = {new_str}')
```

Comment: Are the numbers separated by comma?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos, no there are no comma

Comment: Your question is nice, but please take the [tour] to learn more about the site.

Comment: @ppwater, okay I check that, thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split()` to split the string into items. Each item represents either a `string`, a `float`, or an `int`. If it's a `string`, we cannot convert it to a number and increment it. If conversion to `float` succeeds, it still might be an `int`, so we try to convert 'further'.

The code still needs handling of float rounding issues - see output.

```
def increment_items(string):
    '''Increment all numbers in a string by one.'''
    items = string.split()

    for idx, item in enumerate(items):
        try:
            repl = False
            nf = float(item)
            repl = nf + 1  # when we reach here, item is at least float ...
            ni = int(item)  # ... but might be int - so we try
            repl = ni + 1  # when we reach here, item is not float, but int
            items[idx] = str(repl)
        except ValueError:
            if repl != False:
                items[idx] = str(repl)  # when we reach here, item is float
    return " ".join(items)

s = "helllo everyone 12 32 how 6.326 is a going?\
 well 7.498 5.8 today Im going 3 to talk 8748 234.0 about\
 python 3 and compare it with python 2"


print('Input:', '\n', s, '\n')
result = increment_items(s)
print('Output:', '\n', result, '\n')
```

**Input:**

```
helllo everyone 12 32 how 6.326 is a going? well 7.498 5.8 today Im going 3 to talk 8748 234.0 about python 3 and compare it with python 2
```

**Output:**

```
helllo everyone 13 33 how 7.326 is a going? well 8.498000000000001 6.8 today Im going 4 to talk 8749 235.0 about python 4 and compare it with python 3
```

Comment: @ack-Thank you, especially for the comments that make it so understandable.

Comment: @Elham - feel free to upvote and/or accept :)

Comment: @ack- one thing is in your code that I don't get it. what is the role of repl?, actually whats the meaning of repl = False,why can't we replace it with this statement=> if not item.isalpha():

Comment: @Elham - my idea was: let python try to do the conversion, without any checking for `isalpha`, `isnumeric`, `isdigit` and such. An exception might occur because 1) we are processing something which does not represent a numeric value (repl == `False`), or, 2) we have something that represents a numeric value, but not an integer (repl == value of the `float`)

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this task is to use *regex*.

---

#### Example 1:

Extract and add 1 to numeric values.

```
import re

nums = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', s)

[int(i) + 1 if i.isdigit() else float(i) + 1 for i in nums]
```

Explanation:

- Use regex to extract all numeric values into a `list`, with or without a decimal.
- Use list comprehension to add 1 to each number, which is converted to either a `float` or `int`, depending on the presence or a decimal.

Regex:
The regex pattern used here extracts any single or repeating digit, as `\d+`. Additionally, there is an *optional non-capture group* (`(?:\.\d+)?`) to capture a decimal and any digits after the decimal, and include this group in the original group, rather than an additional group.

Output:

```
[13, 33, 7.326, 8.498000000000001, 6.8, 4, 8749, 235.0, 4, 3]
```

---

#### Example 2:

Replace numeric values with numeric values +1, in the original string.

The algorithm below follows the same logic as explained in Example 1; with a new list being constructed to contain the updated numeric values, in the string.

```
import re

exp = re.compile(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
r = []

for i in re.split(' |\n', s):
    if re.match(exp, i):
        i = int(i) + 1 if i.isdigit() else float(i) + 1
    r.append(str(i))
```

Output:

```
>>> ' '.join(r)

'helllo everyone 13 33 how 7.326 is a going?  well 8.498000000000001 6.8 today Im going 4 to talk 8749 235.0 about python 4 and compare it with python 3'
```

Comment: thank you for your clear answer and explanation, but is there any way not to use regex function?

Comment: @ElhamYa - My pleasure.  Yes, it is possible -however, I should mention that using regex is a best (robust) approach to this issue, as the `isnumeric` and `isdigit` string functions do not work on floats.  For simple / robust code, I’d strongly recommend using regex, as they can explicitly only match numeric characters.  Think of an example such as `12.1a`.

Comment: @S3DEV- yes you are right, I got your point. Do you know how can I replace the previous numbers with new one in that string?

Comment: @ElhamYa - Yes. I've just updated the answer to include *Example 2* which shows how the replacements can be made. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: @S3DEV- Thank you so much for your helpful solution.